# How to use same javascript filter twice in the same page with different tables?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I wanted to use the same javascript filter on the same page but with two or three different tables and different input field.
 Here below is the script I've been using to filter out dates on a table.
What if there are 2 or more tables?

```
function filterFunction() {
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, totalViewable = 0;
  input = document.getElementById("event_date_range");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("dateTable");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[1];
    tds = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
    if (td) {
      if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
        totalViewable += parseFloat(tds.innerHTML);
        document.getElementById("total_amount_td").innerHTML = "$" + totalViewable.toFixed(2);
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  }
}
```

> Table - dataTable
>   Input field - event_date_range
>   Output text - total_amount_td

Comment: What if your `filterFunction()` accepted a parameter that was the `id` of each table, or perhaps an array of `id` properties?

Comment: I tried and then I had this problem with the innerHTML something when I used the part where I change the `total_amount_td`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass the `table`, `input` and `total_amount_id` as parameters to your `filterFunction`:

Something like:

```
function filterFunction(table, input, total_amount_id) {
  var filter, tr, td, i, totalViewable = 0;
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[1];
    tds = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
    if (td) {
      if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
        totalViewable += parseFloat(tds.innerHTML);
        document.getElementById(total_amount_id).innerHTML = "$" + totalViewable.toFixed(2);
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And then call the function with different parameters:

```
var table1 = document.getElementById("dateTable");
var input1 = document.getElementById("event_date_range");
var total_amount_id1 = "total_amount_td";
filterFunction(table1, input1, total_amount_id1);
var table2 = document.getElementById("dateTable2");
var input2 = document.getElementById("event_date_range2");
var total_amount_id2 = "total_amount_td2";
filterFunction(table2, input2, total_amount_id2);
```